# Как заставить Spring Boot читать конфигурацию подключения к БД из application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, config, boot

Основные конфигурации прописаны в **hibernate.cfg.xml**. Возникла необходимость перенести пароль, имя пользователя и имя БД в application.properties. Однако заставить систему читать из **application.properties** эти данные не удается. Попытки использовать аннотацию `@PropertySources` и прописывать нужный файл в `.configure()` при инициализации SessionFactory к успеху не привели.
Как сообщать Spring'у, что читать пароль, пользователя и имя БД нужно в **application.properties**?
Service.java:

```
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("application.properties") }) // не помогло
@Service
public class Service {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml") // тут менял hibernate.cfg.xml на application.properties
            .addAnnotatedClass(FileEntity.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();

---методы обращения к БД---

}
```

Часть hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="com.group.appName.model.FileEntity" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=9090
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
```

ApplicationContextConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.group.appName")
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(FireService.class);
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(FileEntity.class);
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager" )
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver getCommonsMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520); // 20MB
        multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);  // 1MB
        return multipartResolver;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример рабочей конфигурации, но для Postgres

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.1.2.15/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=your_db
spring.datasource.password=your_pass
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Comment: Я добавлял в **application.properties** и полную конфигурацию, и оставлял там только пароль, юзера и url (в **hibernate.cfg.xml** эти строки закоментил) - не работает. Spring просто не читает то, что записано в **application.properties** :-(

Comment: А где лежит application.properties? В src/main/resources/? Какие строки выдает SPRING BOOT при запуске? Там должно быть про пулл коннектов, драйвер БД.  spring.datasource.driverClassName и spring.jpa.database-platform должны быть в application.properties.

Comment: @Orthodox, да, application.properties лежит там, где нужно. не увидел сразу Ваш ответ. Уже разобрался. Спасибо.